# how to use cast to reshape dataframe

Tags: r, reshape

I use the below code to reshape my data set that consist of ID, Rank, Salary columns

```
library(reshape)
transdara = as.data.frame(cast(populations,ID~Rank, 
                               fun.aggregate = sum, value = "salary"))
transdara
```

but it give this error message:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(sort_df(data, variables), , c(variables, "value"),  : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Data:

```
    ID  Rank    Salary
326 AssocProf   126431
11  AssocProf   119800
218 AssocProf   118700
199 AssocProf   113600
92  AsstProf    97032
152 AsstProf    95079
200 AsstProf    92700
204 AsstProf    92700
44  Prof    231545
368 Prof    205500
253 Prof    204000
275 Prof    194800
78  Prof    193000
334 Prof    192253
202 Prof    189409
```

Comment: Your code can't be reproduced by others, are you able to provide your data (`populations`) by using `dput(populations)`?

Comment: thank you I add part of the data in the answer

Comment: You need to capitalize `Salary` in your original code; R is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(reshape)
df <- data.frame(ID = c(326, 11, 218, 199, 92, 152, 200, 204, 44, 368, 253, 275, 
                        78, 334, 202),
                 Rank = c('AssocProf', 'AssocProf', 'AssocProf', 'AssocProf', 
                          'AsstProf', 'AsstProf', 'AsstProf', 'AsstProf', 'Prof',
                          'Prof', 'Prof', 'Prof', 'Prof', 'Prof', 'Prof'),
                 Salary =c(126431, 119800, 118700, 113600, 97032, 95079, 92700,
                           92700, 231545, 205500, 204000, 194800, 193000, 192253,
                           189409))
transdara = as.data.frame(cast(df, ID ~ Rank, 
                               fun.aggregate = sum, 
                               value = 'Salary'))
transdara
```